# Compare position of markers in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of Google Maps Markers that I get after clicking on cluster.

I would need to check if the markers of this array have the same position. Because I can find myself in the situation where it could be, where in one cluster all of markers have the same position.

There is my code :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
    map.setCenter(markers[0].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+10);
    for(i in markers) {
        // Here, how to compare each marker (by comparing the position) between them of markers ?
        markers[i].setMap(cluster.getMap());
        marker = markers[i];
    }
    cluster.clusterIcon_.hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    },100);
});
```

So my question, is how to compare each marker (by comparing the position) between them of markers array ? How to check if they have the same position ?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

I found the solution :

```
const bounds = cluster.getBounds();
const areMarkersCoincident = bounds.getNorthEast().equals(bounds.getSouthWest());
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you want to check if the markers are identical, you can compare their `lot` and `lan`. If you want to detect close markers, you can calculate the distance between them - https://www.google.com/amp/s/cloudblog.withgoogle.com/products/maps-platform/how-calculate-distances-map-maps-javascript-api/amp/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
For example, if you just need a simple clustering solution you can just use google maps marker clusters: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

But for something else you can just compare positions of the markers.
For that, you have latitude and longitude.

Here you can read the documentation of LatLng class in google maps and see that it has method `equals` which can compare two coordinates. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng

But don't forget that in some cases you might need to compare not just marker positions, but also if the marker icons intersect. For that, you can either use LatLngBounds https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds and it has a method `contains`